# What does zero-sized array allocation do/mean?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Looking at some example code and come across some zero-size array allocation. I created the following code snippet to clarify my question

This is valid code:

```
class T
{
};

int main(void)
{
  T * ptr = new T[0];

  return 0;
}
```

What is its use? Is ptr valid? Is this construct portable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

5.3.4 in the C++ Standard:

6 Every *constant-expression* in a *direct-new-declarator* shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and evaluate to a strictly positive value. The *expression* in a *direct-new-declarator* shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1) with a non-negative value...

7 When the value of the *expression* in a *direct-new-declarator* is zero, the allocation function is called to allocate an array with no elements.

So, your code allocates an array which behaves in every respect like any other array of T (can be deleted with delete[], passed as a parameter, probably other things). However, it has no accessible indexes (that is, reading or writing ptr[0] results in undefined behaviour).

In this context the different between the constant-expression and the expression is not whether the actual expression is compile time constant (which obviously 0 is), but whether it specifies the "last" dimension of a multi-dimensional array. The syntax is defined in 5.3.4:1.

Answer (score 2):

It is authorized (5.3.4/6). Its result is an empty array, so the value returned is the pointer past the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid behaviour, and ptr will be valid. The construct is portable to all C++ compilers that adhere to the C++ Standard. It is useful in that it allows you to write code which doesn't require special-case stuiff to handle the case where the number of elements is zero.

However, as always, you will be better served by using a std::vector (which can also be zero-sized) instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

A related question is: [What should malloc(0) return?](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/578467-what-malloc-0-should-returns)

[And from some C99 docs](http://docs.sun.com/source/819-3688/c99Implementation.app.html), the malloc(0) behavior is implementation-defined:

> Whether the calloc, malloc, and
>   realloc functions return a null
>   pointer or a pointer to an allocated
>   object when the size requested is zero
>   (7.20.3).
>
> Either a null pointer or a unique
>   pointer that can be passed to free()
>   is returned.
>
> See the malloc(3C) man page.

Granted you're asking about C++, but the malloc info is probably useful anyway.